# Beautiful Soup Web scraping Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this code Html on a website:

[![![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is my python script:

```
import csv 
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

csv_file = open('C:\\Users\scrap_result.csv','w',newline='')


csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
csv_writer.writerow(['headline', 'price', 'img_src'])

for page in range (1,3):
    url = "https://test.vn/products?page=/{}/".format(page)
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
    
for productname in soup.find_all('productname'):
    headline = productname.h6.text
    
    price= productname.find('h6',class_='product-card__name').text
    img_src = productname.find('picture',class_='product-card__image mb-3 lozad').img['src']
    
    print(headline)
    print(price)
    print(img_src)
    csv_writer.writerow([headline, price, img_src])
csv_file.close()
```

When i run it, it returns empty values. I guess im not calling the right tags but cant figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything that is called "productname" in the html. So maybe `soup.find_all(productname)` returns an empty list.

By the way: the for-loops aren't nested, so the second loop starts after the first one has finished and only the last url is searched.